# Orthogonality Property of theProduction of two Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis

If the product of matrices say $\ \hat{N}  \hat{M} $  is symmetric  $\ \left(\hat{N}\hat{M} \right)^T= \hat{N}\hat{M} $ (where T means transpose ) and $\ \hat{N} $  has the form of $\   \hat{N}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&\textrm{Identity Matrix}\\\textrm{Identity Matrix}&0\end{pmatrix} $. How can we prove that eigenvectors of the Matrix $\ \hat{M} $ ($\ \hat{M} \vec v=\lambda\vec v $)
have the orthogonality property.
    $\ (\vec v)^T \hat{N}\vec v=\delta_{ij} $.

Thank you very much.

It is the equation (16) from this paper

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/m0l566pi2z60boi0zadb4/1-s2.0-016521259290033X-main.pdf?dl=0&oref=e&r=AAWY_3uH7_BvhLaX5VHAcnQ8sGjn_rOO7mrMuASafjK9oMn9H9cI9x99X8WnZ8cwRsw_sy3sx9tlXQbYSezWSu7GmwWTvA-JWm6E2cdTZr1L3sy_aBJWYQVdPEaD5SZ8C6sj8b1duBzzvBe7NUzQjYDtz4TSpgqsBlpLgkWjtsqFnIDm_bXav9-AUBHftXBicXU&sm=1

Comment: Are the matrices real or complex? Or any other field?

Comment: Thank you very much for your respond. I came upon to this problem in some crystallography paper. And I think I forgot the linear algebra course that I had in university.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nsyz59j5l1enfxf/1-s2.0-016521259290033X-main.pdf?dl=0

Comment: The matrices can be considered real, I don't think that will change anything.

Comment: another thing is unclear. you wrote M has the form N= . which one has that form N or M?

Comment: Sorry, It should've been N there. I fixed it.

Comment: OK there are still problems with your question.  the definition of the orthogonality property doesn't make sense. one side of the equality has indices while the other side doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $v_{i},v_{j}$ be eigenvectors of $M$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_{i},\  \lambda_{j}$ respectively. We assume $\lambda_{i}\neq \lambda_{j}$ . We note $u^{T}Nv$ by $<u,v>_{N}$. Notice that $N^{T}=N$ so we have $NM=(NM)^{T}=M^{T}N^{T}=M^{T}N$. We observe that $$\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda_{i}\left\langle v_{i},v_{j}\right\rangle _{N} & = & v_{i}^{T}M^{T}Nv_{j}\\
 & = & v_{i}^{T}NMv_{j}\\
 & = & v_{i}^{T}N\lambda_{j}v_{j}\\
 & = & \lambda_{j}\left\langle v_{i},v_{j}\right\rangle _{N}
\end{eqnarray*}$$  This implies $\left\langle v_{i},v_{j}\right\rangle _{N}=0$. If $v_{i}$ is an eigenvector then so is $cv_{i}$ therefore If we want  $\left\langle v_{i},v_{i}\right\rangle _{N}=1$ we need to choose normlized vectors to begin with.